# What is the difference between Schwarz space and compactly supported continous space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the difference between $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

We know that they are both continuously differentiable and also element of $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$  is rapidly decreasing.

Does it mean rapidly decreasing to $0$ or any number ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remark: compactly supported continuous functions are usually denoted by $C_c$ and not by $C_0$. $C_0$ is the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Schwartz space contains functions like
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\exp(-(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2))$$
but $C_0^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ doesn't, since $f$ is not compactly supported.

However $C_0^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ is a subspace of the Schwartz space.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  when we say rapidly decreasing, It means it decreases fast but it decreses to What  (0 or any number )?

Comment: Rapidly decreasing means the function is $O(r^{-k})$ for all $k$ where $r^2=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$. This example decreases exponentially which certainly means rapidly decreasing. The Schwartz space consists of rapidly decreasing functions, all of whose partial derivatives of all orders exist and are also rapidly decreasing.